# DOM update spikes with angular 2 *ngFor and golden-layout

Tags: dom, angular, docking, ngfor

Dear fellow Angular 2 developpers,

Me and my team are facing a strange performance issue with our angular 2 application (2.1.1). We are using a docking layout, based on golden-layout.js (https://golden-layout.com/). It works wonderfully and drag-&-drop actions are rendered smoothly.

However, when we have a lot of angular components (let’s say, an *ngFor with around 2500 elements, each of them a simple component with 2 property bindings), golden-layout acts strangely: 
When we click onto an angular component and then start dragging, the drag actions is rendered with huge spikes. However, when we click on an empty space in the browser (NOT on the HTML of any angular component) and then start dragging, the animation is running smoothly.

All our components use ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush and where possible, ChangeDetectors are detached and updating is triggered manually.
We suspect angular to keep something like the last ‚focussed‘ component in memory and perform tons of update animations when this focussed element is an angular component.

Any ideas where this problem might come from or what we should search for? Since we see that the rendering does work fine when we click outside of any angular component, there has to be a reason, yet we cannot think of a way of properly diagnosing our problem.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: I created a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ipqdOlRBEdZjvtiujMGb?p=preview):

```
 placeholder (sorry, cannot just post relevant portion)
```

The phenomenon can be reproduced as follows:

**Initial state**: Drag aroung any Simple Component. The animation should be smooth.
**Spikes**: Click inside the Complex component (which contains 5000 elements). Then drag. The animation should render with very few frames.
**Fix**: Perform a double click into any Simple Component, followed by a single click, then try dragging again. The animation should be smooth again.

The fix can also be achieved by clicking around randomly in the simple components, we have not figured out the logic behind the whole thing yet. But double clicking and then single clicking works consitently (in the latest Chrome on several 64bit Windows 10 machines at least).

Comment: I guess this needs at least a Plunker to reproduce.